# Prevent calling ajax while function is running in endless loop

Tags: ajax, function, loops

I am trying to create a live sales number for my company, and I want to use Ajax to do this. In order to achieve my goal, I want it to call the function to get the numbers, as soon as the function finishes, so:

When page loads, it will call function1(); When function1() is done, it will call it again. WHILE function1() is running, it should not call the function.

Comment: Confusing, add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've needed to do this in the past I've simply created an isRunning boolean flag.

Upon page load you'd set isRunning to False.

When function1() starts you would set this variable to TRUE.  Then at end of function when its completed, you would set it to FALSE.

then wherever you're initiating the call to function1() (on some predefined interval), you'd first check the value of the variable and ONLY run function1() when isRunning is found to be FALSE.   If isRunning is TRUE, then the function1() call is bypassed and checked at next interval / loop iteration.